# MYSQL, get both matching and null data

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have Three tables

Table_1 : Vehicles

```
id name
-------
1  Honda
2  Ferrari
3  wagon
```

Table_2 : extra_details

```
ID        Detail
------------------------
1          GPS
2          CAMERA
3          Tracking System
```

Table_3 : vehcile_extras

```
vehicle_id      extra_detail_id 
--------------------------
1                2
1                3
3                2
```

Now one vehicle may have more than 1 additional things like GPS , Tracking System etc so i create 1 extra
table for store those things with vehicle id and extra_detail_id 

**i want all vehicles data, if some vehicle have extra details i show those with comma separated if not than null 
 My Query**

My Query:

```
  SELECT v.* , GROUP_CONCAT(e.name SEPARATOR ', ') as additional_details FROM vehicles v 
  left join vehcile_extras ve on ve.vehicle_id = v.id
  left join extra_details e on FIND_IN_SET(ve.extra_detail_id, e.id)
```

Result Something Like ,

```
id     name     additional_details 
----------------------------------
1      Honda    CAMERA,Tracking System
3      wagon    CAMERA
```

**I want like this**

```
id     name     additional_details 
----------------------------------
1      Honda    CAMERA,Tracking System
2      Ferrari  null
3      wagon    CAMERA
```

**i know i can achieve this with UNION ALL , but i want to know if there is any other trick to get all the data without union ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coul be you need  a proper group by

```
  SELECT  v.id, v.name , GROUP_CONCAT(e.name SEPARATOR ', ') as additional_details 
  FROM vehicles v 
  left join vehcile_extras ve on ve.vehicle_id = v.id
  left join extra_details e on FIND_IN_SET(ve.extra_detail_id, e.id)
  GROUP BY  v.id, v.name
```

or also avoid FIND_IN_SET

```
 SELECT v.id, v.name , GROUP_CONCAT(e.name SEPARATOR ', ') as additional_details 
 FROM vehicles v 
 left join vehcile_extras ve on ve.vehicle_id = v.id
 left join extra_details e on ve.extra_detail_id =  e.id
 GROUP BY  v.id, v.name
```

Comment: thanks , can you please explain how this group by solve the problem ?

Comment: because the use of an aggregation function without group by produce unpredictable result and don't return null rows ..  .. this behaviour is allowed  (by default) with mysql <5.7  ..  for mysql 5.7 or later the use of mixed  aggregation function a not aggregated  columns produce an error ..   hope is clear ..

Comment: brother, you know the solution of this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523296/mysql-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-with-increment-in-varchar