# MYSQL, copy data from one table to another table with increment in varchar

Tags: mysql

I have Two tables

Table_1 : users

```
id name
-------
1  john
2  john2
3  john3
```

Table_2 : tbl_account_level

```
ID    Code      Detail
------------------------
1     00001     GPS
2     00002     CAMERA
3     00003     Tracking System
```

**Now, i want to copy all the data from users table into tbl_account_level through mysql , and the code number is Varchar .**

My Query:

```
  insert into tbl_account_level (code, detail)select cast("00003" as unsigned) + 1, name from users ;
```

Result Something Like ,

```
ID    Code      Detail
------------------------
1     00001     GPS
2     00002     CAMERA
3     00003     Tracking System
4     4         john
5     5         john2
6     6         john3
```

I want Result Something like

```
ID    Code      Detail
------------------------
1     00001     GPS
2     00002     CAMERA
3     00003     Tracking System
4     00004     john
5     00005     john2
6     00006     john3
```

Comment: Can I suggest you just store integers as integers - you seem to be confusing issues of data display with issues of data storage and retrieval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lpad  for adding the leading 0 after the increment

```
insert into tbl_account_level (code, detail)
select lpad(cast(code  as unsigned) + 1, 5 ,'0'), name 
from users
```

and if you need row increment you coudl use a multi statement as

```
SET @row_number = 0; 
insert into tbl_account_level (code, detail)
select lpad(cast(code  as unsigned) +  @row_number:=@row_number + 1, 4 ,'0'), name 
from users ;
```

Comment: But why would you :-( ?

Comment: Brother, it's return me same code means it's not add + 1 in every record, i also try with sub query like select code from table order by id DEC limit 1, did i need any loop here ? please see the attach image : https://ibb.co/1Q047Cm

Comment: you can do as I did ..
I have read all the manuals and for each instruction of tried to understand how it works .. today the easiest because it is manual and any test and trial environments can be found directly online .. .. if you need  db a deep knowledge of sql and sql dialet is mandatory